# Correct way to get a Python Exception object by name/string

Tags: python, exception

I have a distributed system communicates using pub-sub model. The publishers are background services that should be long running. Subscribers are user applications that should stop and raise Exceptions when something is wrong. So error messages from the publisher are passed to subscribers in JSON messages such as:

```
"result": {
    "exc_type": "ValueError", 
    "exc_message": ["Error retrieving remote file. Response status: %s"], 
    "exc_module": "builtins"
}
```

In this example, I want the subscriber app to do something like

```
raise ValueError(f'error in publisher module {result["exc_module"]}, error message: {result["exc_message"]}')
```

What's the correct way to get the exception object from the string in "exc_type" field programmatically?

What I doing now is to call it from the Python `__builtins__` dict:

```
x = __builtins__[result["exc_type"]]
```

But this seems like a hack rather than the appropriate way.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: If you trust the publisher, you could use `eval()`... If not, then yeah I'd probably create an exceptions dictionary which maps the names to the exception classes (all the exceptions you are expecting and will want to handle), then use `raise exceptions.get(exc_type, Exception("Unknown Error"))`.

Comment: Less hacky would be to use `importlib.import_module` to load the specified module in which to find the exception type. `getattr(import_module(result['exc_module']), result['exc_type'])(result['exc_message'])`.

Comment: At least, I find it no more hacky than embedding Python-specific exception information in a language-agnostic format like JSON.

Comment: @chepner, I am working with a legacy system that came with the JSON message. What would you suggest if I can replace the JSON with some other message format?